# Sort by most "trending" (most clocked) rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, scope

I'm a noob so I appologize in advance for my lack of clarity and/or simplicity of this question.

I am trying to sort products in my product index.html.erb in 4 ways. Three of which are working but the "Trending" Function is not. I am having trouble ordering by clock.size (which may have something to do with the table or associations between clocks and products - I am unsure obviously)

Any help would be great! Thanks.

routes.rb

```
Kijovo::Application.routes.draw do

root "welcome#index"

get "products/filter/:scope" => "products#index", as: :filtered_products

resources :products do
resources :clocks
end
end
```

products_controller.rb

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :require_signin
 before_action :require_admin, except: [:index, :show]
 before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index

@product = Product.find_by(params[:id])

case params[:scope] 
  when 'past'
    @products = Product.past
  when 'upcoming'
    @products = Product.upcoming
  when 'tba'
    @products = Product.tba
  else
    @products = Product.trending
  end

end
```

product.rb (Product Model)

```
 class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clocks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :clockers, through: :clocks, source: :user

 before_validation :generate_slug

 validates :slug, uniqueness: true


  # scope :trending, -> { where("releasing_on >= ?", Time.now).order("clocks.size") }
 scope :trending, -> { joins(:clocks).where("releasing_on >= ?", Time.now).order("clocks.size") }
 scope :upcoming, -> { where("releasing_on >= ?", Time.now).order("releasing_on").order(:name) }
 scope :past, -> { where("releasing_on <= ?", Time.now).order("releasing_on desc").order(:name) }
 scope :tba, -> { where(releasing_on: nil).order(:name) }

 end
```

products_helper.rb

```
module ProductsHelper

def format_price(product)
  if product.tbd?
  "TBD"
  else
    number_to_currency(product.price)
  end
  end


def format_releasing_on(product)
  if product.tba?
  "TBA"
  else
      product.releasing_on
  end
  end

 def format_releasing_on_remaining(product)
   if product.tba?
      ""
    elsif product.out?
      "OUT"
    else
     (product.releasing_on - DateTime.now).to_i
  end
 end

end
```

Products -- index.html.erb

```
<header>

<div class="row">
<div class="span12 centered-pills">  

 <nav> 
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
   <li><%= link_to 'Trending', filtered_products_path(:trending) %></li>
   <li><%= link_to 'Releasing Soon', filtered_products_path(:upcoming) %></li>
   <li><%= link_to 'Just Released', filtered_products_path(:past) %></li>
   <li><%= link_to 'TBA', filtered_products_path(:tba) %></li>
  </ul>
 </nav> 

</div>
</div>

</header>
```

clock.rb (Clock Model)

```
class Clock < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Clock Table Schema

```
  create_table "clocks", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Product table schema

```
  create_table "products", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.decimal  "price"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.date     "releasing_on"
    t.string   "website"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "industry"
    t.string   "slug"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.string   "company"
    t.integer  "total_clocks"
  end
```

Failing SQL In Rails console:

```
2.0.0-p576 :037 > Product.joins(:clocks).where("releasing_on >= ?", Time.now).order("clocks.size")

  Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "clocks" ON "clocks"."product_id" = "products"."id" WHERE (releasing_on >= '2014-11-07 18:55:15.595051') ORDER BY clocks.size
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: clocks.size: SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "clocks" ON "clocks"."product_id" = "products"."id" WHERE (releasing_on >= '2014-11-07 18:55:15.595051')  ORDER BY clocks.size

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: clocks.size: SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "clocks" ON "clocks"."product_id" = "products"."id" WHERE (releasing_on >= '2014-11-07 18:55:15.595051')  ORDER BY clocks.size
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to sort by `clocks`, you have to join that table in your statement, e.g:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clocks  

  # ...
  scope :trending, -> { joins(:clocks).group("#{Product.table_name}.id").where("releasing_on >= ?", Time.now).order("count(clocks.product_id)") }
end
```

Comment: thanks! I am getting an error that "clocks.size" is not part of the product table. I added an integer column titled total_clocks hoping I could call the products clock.size in it but I am unsure how to do that.

I added the tables that make up my products and clocks maybe that will help?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Added it - that is what I get using the scope with joins(:clocks)

Comment: Well, since `clocks` table does not have field `size`, it fails. What do you mean by `order("clocks.size")`?

Comment: Hmm.. well The sites user can browse products and "clock them" (like them). I am looking to sort products by their clock count. When I call a product in the console and call "clocks.size" on it - it returns the number of clocks (likes) on that product.

For example. Product A has been "clocked" by 10 users, Product B has been "clocked" by 5 users, and Product C has been "clocked" by 20 users.. therefore, according to the scope for "Trending" the products would return in the following order - CAB

Comment: Is there anyway to have "total_clocks" (An integer column I added to the products table) reveal the said products "clocks.size" and then I can sort via that by calling `order("total_clocks")` ?

Comment: I've updated my answer, but didn't check for SQLite.